# I like to add percentage on my bars on the chart on python

Tags: python-3.x, countplot

here not able to put percentage label on bars... please help me out... if anyone figured it out

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMVM7.jpg)

Finding the solution of the problem tried few codes but not worked. I am new to python. Any suggestion would help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.